# Small 6 Axis Force Torque Sensor

Tags: robotic-arm, torque, sensor, force, force-sensor

currently I need to install an suitable 6 Axis Force Torque Sensor on my Robotic arm. It has to be small beacause it will be mounted on this Robot: https://www.wlkata.com/en-de/pages/pg-mirobot-intro
Therefore it has to be small and leightweight (like this one: https://www.aidinrobotics.co.kr/miniature-6-axis-ft-sensor but probalby a little bit cheaper).

Do you have any experiences with comparable Sensors/recommendations? And do you have any alternative Ideas how I could measure the Forces on my Endeffector?